# JPA UniqueContraint in Inner class

Tags: java, jpa

I have a question about JPA uniqueConstraint.

I have a PlayerJPA class with a uniqueConstraint in a (String) Nickname field but I want to add a constraint to the email field which is in a inner object : PersonalInformations.
(I don't want that two players have the same personalInformations)

```
        @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "player.findAll", query = "select p from PlayerJPA p"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "person.removeAll", query = "delete from PlayerJPA "),
        @NamedQuery(name = "person.findByEmail", query = "select p from PlayerJPA p where p.personalInformations.email= :email"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "person.deleteByEmail", query = "delete from PlayerJPA P where p.personalInformations.email= :email")}
    )

    @Entity
    @Table( name = "PLAYER",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"NICK_NAME", "EMAIL"})})
    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @CascadeOnDelete
    public class PlayerJPA implements IPlayer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="ID")
    private long id;


    @Column(name = "NICK_NAME")
    @NickName
    private String nickName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL")
    private PersonalInformationsJPA personalInformations;

    public PlayerJPA(){

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    public PersonalInformationsJPA getPersonalInformations() {
        return personalInformations;
    }

    public void setPersonalInformations(PersonalInformationsJPA personalInformations) {
        this.personalInformations = personalInformations;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return display();
    }
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't work with the line :

```
  @Table( name = "PLAYER",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"NICK_NAME", "EMAIL"})})
```

Do you know how can I do this  ?

Thanks you a lot !

Comment: what does "it doesn't work" mean? When you run schema creation it doesn't create the constraint? and which JPA implementation?

Comment: This looks like you defined a single constraint to make the combination of both columns unique. I think you want two constraints, one for each column.

Comment: For single-column constraints, you can use the more concise `@Column(unique=true)` on each property.

Comment: When i run the schema creation, 2 rows are created instead of 1 or to genereate an error.

But now it's ok, thanks to Thilo !

Comment: It looks like `PersonalInformationsJPA` is a separate entity which is stored in a separate table. In that case you could create two separate constraints: 1) a unique constraint for player name -> no 2 players with the same name 2) a unique constraint on player + email on `PersonalInformationsJPA` -> only one player can have that email address.

Comment: When you run schema creation there are NO ROWS CREATED. THIS IS SCHEMA CREATION. Not RUNTIME. Is the CONSTRAINT created??? Why not actually print out the DDL issued to the datastore?